# How to access an item selected from the list in multiple places or functions

Tags: python, pygame

Here I'm trying to make a game I have 3 images of blocks which are in **blck_array** I want to select one random item from that list and make it travel from top to bottom at the pre-specified(x-pos) which are in **blck_pos**. So the problem is I've created a function **rand_block** to select a random block from list,so that selected image should be accessible both in
**create_block** and **move_block** to perform some operation.I'm getting stuck on how
to use that randomly selected block at both functions.

```
import pygame, sys,random
    
    def rand_block():
        global blck
        blck = random.choice(blck_array)
    
    def create_block():
        rand_block()
        blck=blck.get_rect(midtop = (random.choice(blck_pos),-50))
        return blck
    
    def move_block(blocks):
        for block in blocks:
            block.centery-=5
        return blocks
    def draw_block(blocks):
        rand_block()
        for block in blocks:
            screen.blit(blck,block)
    # blocks
    blocks={
        1:pygame.image.load('blocks/BLOCK L.png'),
        2:pygame.image.load('blocks/BLOCK S.png'),
        3:pygame.image.load('blocks/BLOCK M.png'),
        }
    blck_array=[blocks[1],blocks[2],blocks[3]]
    blck_pos=[0,47,553,190,250]
    
    block_list=[]
    
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 600))
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    
    SPAWNPIPE=pygame.USEREVENT
    pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1200)
    
    bal_x=0
    loop = True
    
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==SPAWNPIPE:
                block_list.append(create_block)
    
    
    
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        block_list=move_block(block_list)
        draw_block(block_list)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two proposed solutions:

1. I think perhaps define your functions after you define the `blck_array` and do `blck = random.choice(blck_array)`, without needing a function.  So something like this:

```py
blck_array = [blocks[1], blocks[2], blocks[3]]
blck = random.choice(blck_array)
def create_block():
...
```

2. Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the `rand_block` function, then what you could do is have it return `blck`.  So, something like this:

```py
def rand_block(arr): # arr is the list of blocks (blck_array), which should be provided as input
    return random.choice(arr)
```

Then, you could use the returned value as blck.  So you can write, `blck = rand_block(block_array)` where needed.